# How I can pass the current object from an array as a prop of a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, components

I'm doing my personal portifolio. For the projects component I did an array of objects at another file. Each object/item is one project. I used a map to display dynamicaly the items, so if I add a project(object) in the array, it will automatically be displayed. I want that when someone click in a button of one of the projects apears a pop up with some aditional infos about the clicked project. For this I did a Modal Component and I pass the item/object as a props, but when the Modal apears, the infos are of the last item of the array and not of the current/clicked, I don't know exaclty why. 
**The Project Component**

```
import { PlusCircle, Plus } from 'phosphor-react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { data } from '../data/data.js'
import { Modal } from './Modal.js';

export const Projects = () => {
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
    // projects file
    const project = data;
    //setProject(data);
  
  return (
    <div name='projects' className='w-full md:h-screen text-white bg-dark'>
      <div className='max-w-[1000px] mx-auto p-4 flex flex-col justify-center w-full h-full'>
        <div className='pb-8'>
          <p className='text-4xl font-mono font-bold inline border-b-4 text-white border-cyan-200'>
            Projects
          </p>
          <p className='py-6'>// Check out some of my recent work</p>
          <p className='hidden md:flex'>Scroll to see more</p>
          <p className='md:hidden'>Click to see more</p>
        </div>

{/* container for projects */}
<div className="grid sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
          
          {/* Gird Item */}
          {project.map((item, index) => (
  <div
    key={index}
    style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${item.image})` }}
    className="shadow-lg shadow-[#040c16] group container rounded-md 
              flex flex-col justify-center text-center  mx-auto content-div overflow-hidden"
  >
    {/* Hover effect for images */}
    <div className="opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 flex flex-col group justify-center align-middle items-center pt-6">
      <span className="text-2xl font bold text-white tracking-wider ">
        {item.name}
      </span>
      <div className='flex justify-center items-center gap-1'>
        <p className=''>Click here to see the description</p>
        <PlusCircle size={22} className='cursor-pointer hover:rotate-180 duration-300' onClick={()=>{setOpenModal(true)}}/>
        
      </div>
      <div className="pt-5 pb-4 text-center ">
        {/* eslint-disable-next-line */}
        <a href={item.live} target="_blank">
          <button
            className="text-center rounded-lg px-4 py-3 m-2
                       bg-white text-gray font-bold text-lg"
          >
            Demo
          </button>
        </a>
        {/* eslint-disable-next-line */}
        <a href={item.github} target="_blank">
          <button
            className="text-center rounded-lg px-4 py-3 m-2
                       bg-white text-gray font-bold text-lg"
          >
            Code
          </button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    {openModal && <Modal setOpenModal={setOpenModal} item={item} index={index}/>}
    {openModal ? document.body.classList.add('active-modal') : document.body.classList.remove('active-modal')}
    <div className='flex items-start'>
    <div className='justify-center p-[5.1px] gap-1 bg-dark rounded-r-md flex ml-[-200px] group-hover:ml-0 duration-300'>
        {
          item.stack.map( stack => <img className='w-[25px]' src={stack} alt="" />)
        }
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
))}

</div>
      
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**The Modal Component**

```
import { X } from "phosphor-react"


export const Modal = ({setOpenModal, item, index}) => {
  return (
      // Modal Background
      <div key={index} className="w-full h-screen bg-[rgba(49,49,49,0.3)] fixed flex justify-center items-center top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 text-black">
      {/* Modal Container */}
      <div className="w-[700px] h-[650px] rounded-[12px] bg-white shadow-md flex flex-col ">
          <div className="flex justify-end">
              <X size={25} className="text-[red] cursor-pointer fixed -ml-1 mt-1" onClick={()=>{setOpenModal(false)}}/>
          </div>
          {/* Tittle */}
          <div
            key={index}
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${item.image})` }}
            className="container 
                    flex flex-col justify-center text-center rounded-t-lg mx-auto bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-center h-[100%] overflow-hidden"
        ></div>
          <div key={index} className="inline-block text-center mt-2 text-[22px] font-mono font-bold">
              <h1>{item.name}</h1>
          </div>
          {/* Body */}
          <div className="flex flex-col flex-[50%] justify-center items-center text-justify text-md px-12">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et purus tempus, cursus ex vitae, pretium urna. Curabitur et lectus eget eros gravida fermentum et sit amet tellus. Quisque blandit suscipit nisi vitae volutpat. Curabitur mattis lectus mauris, ut scelerisque tortor blandit a. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum eget elit maximus, porttitor velit ac, ultrices est.</p>
          </div>
          {/* Footer */}
          <div className="flex flex-[50%] justify-center items-center mt-0">
            <a href={item.live} target="_blank">
                <button
                    className="text-center rounded-lg px-4 py-3 m-2
                            bg-cyan-800 text-white font-bold text-lg"
                >
                    Demo
                </button>
            </a>
                {/* eslint-disable-next-line */}
            <a href="https://github.com" target="_blank">
                <button
                    className="text-center rounded-lg px-4 py-3 m-2
                            bg-cyan-800 text-white font-bold text-lg"
                >
                    Code
                </button>
            </a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Your `openModal` is global for all your `Modal` objects. Once you set it to `true` in the `onclick` handler, it makes all the `Modals` visible because all of them are driven by a single state. It would be best if you changed this so that each `Modal` will have its own state, and clicking on a `project` will only show a single specific `Modal` associated with this `project`.

Comment: You see your last `Modal` because once `openModal` is set and all your `Modals` become visible, rendering of the last one for the last project stays on the screen.

Comment: I would also recommend splitting `html` of the `Projects` component into multiple components. For example, you can clearly move a single project `html` into a new `Project` component.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I solved It creating another state to storage the value of the current index. So when I click in the button it sets the state of the current index and the state of the modal. 
```<PlusCircle size={22} className='cursor-pointer hover:rotate-180 duration-300' onClick={()=>{setThisIndex(index) ;setOpenModal(true)}}/>```.

And to display, it compare if the modal state is true and the index equal to the current index state. ```{openModal && (index===thisIndex) && <Modal setOpenModal={setOpenModal} item={item} index={index}/>}```